# Unable to identify HTML tag unordered list paragraph and replace with custom style bullets

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

I'am trying to find a way to replace or insert Bullets to the unordered list paragraph.I have achieved it in few instances where the HTML unordered bullet list is tagged correctly in the word paragraph.But in the below mentioned paragraph it's not working.

"[ul][li]Thank them and let them know that the company takes their concerns very seriously.
[/li][li]We have formal process in place which has to be followed.
[/li][li]they can report their concerns to the ethical team available,
including:[/li][ul][li]ethical Team[/li][li]Ethics HelpLine, anonymously if preferred
[/li][li]this is considered as risk confirmed[/li][/ul][/ul]"

Below are the two sub procedures for [ul] and [li] which will work sometime, however it is not working for the above paragraph.

```
Sub ullist()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call Copy_styles
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

   objWord.Visible = True

With ActiveDocument.Range.Find

  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.Style = "List Spacing 3"
  .Text = "\[ul\](*)\[/ul\]^13"
  .Replacement.Text = "\1^p"
  .Forward = True
  .Format = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  '.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(0.25)
 
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub lilist()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call Copy_styles
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

   objWord.Visible = True

With ActiveDocument.Range.Find

  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.Style = "List Spacing 3"
  .Text = "\[li\](*)\[/li\]^13"
  .Replacement.Text = "\1^p"
  .Forward = True
  .Format = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please correct me with the script mentioned above for both [ul] and [li] and replace [ul] and [li] with list paragraph bullets

Comment: Word's native format is not HTML. To format a paragraph with bullets, Word expects a List Style. Here's a page showing how to create a list style in Word that you can apply programmatically: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-custom-list-style-microsoft-word/

Comment: @JohnKorchok thanks for your update and inputs on custom or list style article, however have already created custom list style that is List spacing 3 but unable to replace the HTML tags [ul] or [li] in the document paragraph, please help me on the same.

Comment: Be aware, if you don't know what property and methods should be used for a particular task in Word, you may consider using the VBA macro recorder which can generate the code for you when you do the steps manually.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev Well I tried my best to check the property and methods to work on this code however didn't get through even am unable to achieve the output which is required while recording the macro, is there any other way I can replace the bullets for [ul] and [/ul] for each unordered sentence list